# Doctrine ArrayCollection of objects User

Tags: php, doctrine, arraycollection

I have an Doctrine ArrayCollection of objects User, i want to check if an User exists in this ArrayCollection.

does it exist a method that compare the objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) with `ArrayCollection::exists`